# "Syntax error at or near "202382_" at character 15 "when I execute the below query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax-error, automated-tests

Below is my code, when I execute this code am getting error in the line of 12 as "Syntax error at or near "202382_" at character 15".

```
Set con=createobject("adodb.connection")
Set rs=createobject("adodb.recordset")

con.open"DSN=WC_Vertica_PROD;Autocommit=1;BackupServerNode=;ColumnsAsChar=0;ConnectionLoadBalance=0;ConnSettings=;Database=shr4_hdp_vrt_pro_001;Description=WC_Vertica_PROD;DirectBatchInsert=0;Driver=Vertica;DriverStringConversions=OUTPUT;KerberosHostname=;KerberosServiceName=vertica;Label=;Locale=en_US@collation=binary;Port=5433;PromptOnNoPassword=0;PWD=W0rk1ngCap!pro;ReadOnly=0;ResultBufferSize=131072;Servername=g4t8735.houston.hp.com;SSLMode=prefer;ThreePartNaming=1;TransactionIsolation=Server Default;UID=srvc_wc_hpro"

rs.open "select * from 202382_gf_workingcapital_pro.ovr_spnd_po_drvd_vw",con

Msgbox ("Connection Established")

TotalRows = rs.RecordCount
TotalCols = rs.Fields.Count

Do

For i = 0 To TotalCols-1
For j = 0 To TotalCols-1


Next

ColNames = rs.Fields(i,j).name

Next

rs.MoveNext

Loop until rs.EOF
```

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert but my hunch is that you probably need to be using quoted identifiers around your object name since your database object name does not begin with an alphabetic character.  That is probably why you are getting an error near 202382_.  You might also want to add a tag for your scripting language (VBA?) and format your script as a script for the sake of readability

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers in Oracle cannot start with digits. If this is really your schema's name, you need to quote it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "202382_gf_workingcapital_pro".ovr_spnd_po_drvd_vw
-- Here^---------------------------^
```